# how to get image from outside web path

Tags: php, image, path

i have a php script that generates a array with info

```
Array ( [0] => /mnt/sdb1/files/Copains-16-55-47.jpg 
        [1] => /mnt/sdb1/files/Copains-16-55-41.jpg )
```

now i wanna view this images with

```
<img src="<?php echo $files[0] ?>"  >
<img src="<?php echo $files[1] ?>"  >
```

the page don't show the images

in  the source of the page

```
<img src="/mnt/sdb1/files/Copains-16-55-47.jpg">

<img src="/mnt/sdb1/files/Copains-16-55-41.jpg">
```

where is my fault ?? the path /mnt/sdb1/files has the

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup 4096 aug 25 16:52 files
```

Comment: *Hm...* seems you have spaces at the end of those `<img src="<?php echo $files[0] ?>"  >` that *may* be why. I said "may".

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Since you're using this on a local machine (as seen in comments below), how are you accessing that file, as `http://localhost/file.php`, or `file:///file.php`? Those are two different animals altogether.

Comment: no error reporting , i acces like http://192.168.1.111/file.php

Comment: The correct path must be set in SRC.

Comment: What is the server document path set to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a path problem. Most web servers, for security reasons, will never allow any access to files outside of the document path (eg /var/www/html )

You could sym-link `/mnt/sdb1/files` -> `/var/www/html/files` and re-write the HTML to `<IMG SRC='files/Copains-16-55-47.jpg'>`

You also may need to tell Apache to allow sym-links.

Comment: this is a local server thats runs only local , i have here full root on ,

Answer (score 0):

Check URL in your location:
[YOUR_URL_ON_THIS_SCRIPT]/mnt/sdb1/files/Copains-16-55-47.jpg

If you dont show image.
It`s relative path problem.

Comment: it's a relative path problem , thats sure . but how to solve ? i have made a alias in apache config :  Alias /shots /mnt/sdb1/files , but if i do <img src="shots/Copains-16-55-47.jpg"> i have same problem

Comment: I suggested sym-links in my answer